# How to enable ajax in asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

My ajax is not enabled.

When I press on an ajax Link, the page posts to a partial page.

What is wrong in my code ?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 express
MVC4

**View**

```
  @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

    @Ajax.ActionLink("link", "Test", new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod="POST",
    UpdateTargetId="t",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace
    })
    <div id="t">mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    public PartialViewResult Test ()
    {

        return PartialView("_PTest");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Partial View**

```
<p>partial test</p>
```

**_LayOut**

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Comment: I don't know what is in your bundles.  Make sure you have unobtrusive.ajax referenced.  Google any other files you may need

Comment: thnx ,the problem is solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure Unobtrusive Ajax is referenced. It should be present at the point of creating a new MVC project but if you need details to get it from Nuget, take a look here https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive/